# Remove duplicate extension on file with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been playing around with .htaccess to try and rewrite images for a specific browser (Safari).

I have images uploaded that are named like: `myimage.png.webp` and would like to have the `.webp` removed leaving the `myimage.png` so that the `<img>` tags point to a duplicate file that isn't a WebP.

This is what I tried patching together so far, but it just resulted in a 500 Error and I'm getting myself confused with the rules now. Can anyone help?

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Safari
# check if an image was requested   
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|svg).webp -f
#RewriteRule ^.*/uploads/(.*).(svg|png|jpe?g|gif|bmp).webp$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/uploads/$1.$2 [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directives appear to do the opposite of what you're trying to do, as if you were linking to the `myimage.png.webp` file and *externally* redirecting to the `myimage.png` file?

I assume you are already linking to the `myimage.png` file (as stated). We then need to do some feature sniffing to make sure that the browser can support webp files (and that the `.webp` file actually exists) before rewriting the request.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.$2.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$ /$1.$2.webp [T=image/webp,L]
```

The `T` flag ensures we send back the appropriate mime-type for the webp response.

---

**UPDATE:** It seems you are actually linking to the `.webp` image and wish to rewrite the corresponding png/jpg/gif when webp is not supported (ie. Safari)...

> ```
> # Rewrite images to WebP if they exist
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Safari
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.$2.webp -f
> RewriteRule (.*).(png|jpe?g|gif).webp$ $1.$2 [T=image/$2,L]
> ```

This isn't strictly correct:

- Safari isn't the only browser that doesn't support webp images. Notably, there is IE11 (which still has a reasonable market share, certainly comparible to Safari in some demographics) and other minor browsers (eg. KaiOS). By checking the user-agent, you need to also update the rule when these browsers do support webp images. It is therefore preferable to instead test whether the browser actually supports `image/webp` images (or not) by checking the `Accept` HTTP request header.
- The 2nd condition is checking whether the `.webp` image exists, before rewriting to the non-webp image. Presumably you want to check that the non-webp image exists (or remove this condition altogether - since the request will presumably "fail" anyway if the user-agent does not support webp images).
- The returned mime-type will be incorrect if your images are `.jpg` (as opposed to `.jpeg`) since `image/jpeg` is the correct mime-type, not `image/jpg`. This is harder to fix, unless you split this into its own rule.

Try the following instead:

```
# Rewrite images to non-WebP if webp are not supported and they exist
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.$2 -f
RewriteCond $2@jpeg ^jpe?g@(.+)|(.+)@
RewriteRule (.+)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)\.webp$ $1.$2 [T=image/%1%2,L]
```

The (rather *cryptic*) 3rd condition extracts the required mime-type "part": `png`, `jpeg` or `gif` respectively, regardless of whether `.jpg` or `.jpeg` is requested. These are saved in the `%1` and `%2` backreferences. Note that these are mutually exclusive. Either `%1` holds `jpeg` (and `%2` is empty), OR `%2` holds `png` or `gif` (and `%1` is empty). So *together* they form the correct response.

Note that literal dots in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* don't need to be escaped, since this is an "ordinary" string. However, the literal dots in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* do need to be backslash escaped since this is a regex.

Comment: Thanks for this, though I did mean that the site would have *.webp images embedded in it, but when a visitor comes using safari, it will switch out the webp for a fallback png/jpg based on the webp filename. But this should help get me in the right direction

Comment: Ah, OK, I see what you're saying now. It was the "`<img>` tags point to a duplicate file that isn't a WebP" that threw me (and anubhava by the looks). In actual fact your `<img>` tags _always_ point to the webp image, but this is internally rewritten on the server when using Safari (ie. not supported).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Safari
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp -f
RewriteRule ^.+\.(?:svg|png|jpe?g|gif|bmp)$ $0.webp [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working the way I need, and with a bit of help from the other two answers, my htaccess rule is doing what I expect:

```
# Rewrite images to WebP if they exist
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Safari
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.$2.webp -f
RewriteRule (.*).(png|jpe?g|gif).webp$ $1.$2 [T=image/$2,L]
```

So this will take an image URL like this:
`https://example.com/uploads/test.png.webp` and swap it to a fallback duplicate image on Safari/iOS (where webp *still* isn't supported), and output to the browser: `https://example.com/uploads/test.png`

Comment: I've updated my answer addressing a few issues raised with this code, notably that the wrong mime-type will be sent if requesting `.jpg` images. And testing whether the actual target file exists, rather than the webp image. And user-agent "feature" detection (or lack of), rather than checking explicitly for the Safari browser.